# Unescape protobuf text online

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have logged text from protobuf message that looks like this:

```
message: "\320\227\320\260\320\262\320\265\321\200\321\210\320\265\320\275\320\270\320\265 \321\201\320\262\321\217\320\267\320\270 \321\201 mzta1."
```

How can I unescape it to human readable text using any online tools, console, JS debug console, etc? Without programming.

Comment: It appears to be an octal escape sequence. Try https://en.web-tool.org/hex-oct-decode/ which decodes to "Завершение связи с mzta1." which appears to translate to "Terminating a connection"

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. You should write this comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be an octal escape sequence.

Try [en.web-tool.org/hex-oct-decode](https://en.web-tool.org/hex-oct-decode/) which decodes to "Завершение связи с mzta1." which appears to translate to "Terminating a connection"